# What is a word for someone who tries to comfort their mistakes by trying to reason with him or herself?

Tags: single-word-requests

Is there a word for someone who feels guilty about something they are doing but knows that he or she can't help it so they try to make logic of it and comfort themselves with the reasoning?

Comment: Can you provide one or two examples?

Answer (score 1):

How about **rationalizer**, a person who **rationalizes** or engages in **rationalization**?

From Merriam-Webster:

> [**rationalize**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/rationalize):
>   to think about or describe something (such as bad behavior) in a way
>   that explains it and makes it seem proper, more attractive, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of a noun but often the person is said to be justifying. I've also heard the clumsy word compartmentalizing. It was used often when speaking about President Clinton and how he could compartmentalize actions he was ashamed of in one respect and then would perhaps subconsciously close that proverbial compartment and then open up another one that was more socially acceptable as a way to rationalize in his own mind that they almost were done by two separate people or parts of his personality. Many people do this to deal with darker sides of their personality in order to function in society in day-to-day life as a coping mechanism.

Comment: Self-justification, then?

Comment: Welcome to ELU.SE.This site strives to provide objective answers. Take the [site tour](https://english.stackexchange.com/tour) or have a look at the [help center](https://english.stackexchange.com/help) to find out more about good answers. As it stands your answer is purely subjective.